# executereader process to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Lets say I have a data processing method that triggered from a button click method (winforms)

The business object

```
public class MembershipCard
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string MemberCode { get; set; }
        public string MemberName { get; set; }
        public string MemberCard { get; set; }
        public byte[] MemberCardImage { get; set; }
    }
```

So I want to make the application more responsive, like when retrieving the data I put a multi-line textbox as process status, when doing the execute reader, it'll be like

```
Textbox1.Text = "Retrieving member data, Member Identity" + obj.MemberName ... ... + Environment.NewLine;
```

or when processing like "Processing Member" ...

something like that, because the data is kind of big (>100.000 rows), so after clicking the button, the application will going not responding thing (it's obviously not responsive)

The code I write kind of not working the way that I want

```
using (var reader = mySql.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        MembershipCard obj;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            obj = new MembershipCard();
                            if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")))
                            {
                                obj.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                            }
                            if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("MemberCode")))
                            {
                                obj.MemberCode = Convert.ToString(reader["MemberCode"]);
                            }
                            if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("MemberName")))
                            {
                                obj.MemberName = Convert.ToString(reader["MemberName"]);
                            }
                            if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("MemberCard")))
                            {
                                obj.MemberCard = Convert.ToString(reader["MemberCard"]);
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.MemberCard))
                                {
                                    QRCode qrCode = new QRCode();
                                    qrCode.Data = obj.MemberCard;
                                    qrCode.ModuleSize = 3;

                                    qrCode.LeftMargin = 0;
                                    qrCode.RightMargin = 0;
                                    qrCode.TopMargin = 0;
                                    qrCode.BottomMargin = 0;

                                    qrCode.UOM = UnitOfMeasure.PIXEL;

                                    qrCode.Encoding = BarcodeLib.Barcode.QRCodeEncoding.Auto;
                                    qrCode.ECL = BarcodeLib.Barcode.QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel.L;

                                    qrCode.ImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;

                                    obj.MemberCardImage = qrCode.drawBarcodeAsBytes();
                                }
                            }


                            textBox1.Text = "Getting member data, Member: " + obj.MemberName + "/" + obj.MemberCode + "/" + obj.MemberCard;

                            result.Add(obj);
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
```

TLDR: While performing the `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`, in real time writing the process on a textbox

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays in winforms there are two methods widely used to keep your program responsive when performing big calculations. One is using a background worker, the other is using async-await.

The background worker is better suited for calculations that are not started too often (not several times per second), and that will take some considerable time (several seconds, minutes), because starting a background worker means starting a separate thread with all problems involved (dead lock, InvokeRequired, ...) when the background worker needs to access data that your main thread also accesses.

Async-await is used if you have fairly short calculations that might have to be started often. You use it if you don't want the overhead of starting a new thread, and want code that looks like it is fairly synchronous.

I used to create background workers for my background calculations, retrieving data, writing files, etc, but nowadays I more and more use async-await for this. The code looks much more simpler and is better maintainable.

[This interview with Eric Lippert](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1) helped me a lot to understand how async-await works. Search somewhere in the middle for async await

In this article Eric Lippert compares async-await with a cook preparing a meal. Whenever he has to wait for something to finish, he starts looking around to see if he can do other things instead of waiting idly.

The same is async-await. Whenever your program has to wait for something like a file to be loaded, a database query to be performed, internet data to be down-loaded, the async-await program looks around to see if it can do other things, like responding to user input.

[In this article the ever so helpful Stephen Cleary explains the basics of async-await.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

The main characteristics:

- If a procedure wants to call an async functions it must be declared async itself
- Every async procedure returns `Task` instead of `void` and `Task<TResult>` instead of `TResult`
- There is only one exception: the async event handler returns `void`.
- Normally there is at least one await in your async procedure. In fact, your compiler will warn you if you forgot to await somewhere.
- The return value of the await will be `void` when you await a `Task` and `TResult` when you await `Task<TResult>`.

If your async procedure calls other async procedures, then the code in this other procedure is performed as if it was not an async procedure until it meets an await. Instead of doing nothing the thread goes up its call stack and performs the code until it meets an await. The thread goes up the call stack again, etc. Once everyone is awaiting, it goes back to the first await until this task is finished. Because the UI cannot await for your procedure to finish, you will be certain the as long as your thread isn't doing any calculations (as long as your cook is waiting for the bread to be toasted), your thread is free to keep the UI responsive (the cook is free to do other things)

Note, that if your thread would do the calculations it would not be waiting for something, so your UI would not be responsive. Therefore you should start another thread to perform the calculations, and await for the results only as soon as you need them.

In your case the following code would keep your UI responsive.

```
public async void OnButton1_clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    await this.UpdateData();
    // I chose to split the event from the action, so others like menu items
    // could also call UpdateData();
    // Besides it is a nice example of a function that returns Task instead of void 
}
```

Note that although this event handler is declared async, it returns void.

```
public async Task UpdateData()
{
    // start a Task that will read the database, but don't await
    var myReadTask = Task.Run( () => ReadDatabaseData(...));

    // because you are not awaiting you are free to do other things here
    // like informing the operator that the data is being read:
    // note that this code is performed by the thread that has the UI context
    // so you are free to use the textbox

    Textbox1.Text = "Retrieving member data ...";

    // once you need the data await for it. The return value is the "TResult"
    MyReadData data = await myReadTask;
    // here you are certain that the data has been read
    Textbox1.Text = "Finished reading data";
    ProcessReadData(data);
}
```

`UpdateData` returns `Task` instead of `void`. It is declared async and thus has at least one await in it.

Of course, if you had nothing to do while the data is being read, you could do the following:

```
public async Task UpdateData()
{
    Textbox1.Text = "Retrieving member data ...";
    MyReadData data = await Task.Run( () => ReadDatabaseData(...));
    Textbox1.Text = "Finished reading data";
    ProcessReadData(data);
}
```

The async procedure that will read the data should not do any UI related actions:

```
public async Task<MyReadData> ReadDatabaseData(...)
{
    using (var reader = mySql.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Read the data, don't do anything UI-related
        return myReadData;
    }
}
```

I think the beauty of async-await is that your code looks like it is performed synchronous. There are no race conditions, you don't need to protect critical sections in your code using mutexes. The executing threads have the context of the UI-thread (something like: it can do the things the UI thread could do), you don't need things like `InvokeRequired`.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve data on a separate thread to make UI responsive. Try using background worker.

It is fairly simple. Here is the [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).